# PHP generated iCal - Show event as pending response in Google Calendar

Tags: php, icalendar

I have a php file that generates an iCal output that I can add as a calendar in Google Calendar. It will send employees events that are specific to them and I would like them to be able to accept or decline (much like the native Google functionality - my host won't allow me to use the Google API).

Is it possible to generate events that will show in google calendar as "pending response"? ie: have a hollow circle rather than a solid dot? I would like staff to be able to see event's they have not responded to.

This is what I use to create the events:

```
$ical .= 'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
  'STATUS:TENTATIVE' . "\r\n" .
  'DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Adelaide:'     . $estart_date . "T". $estart_time . "\r\n" .
  'DTEND;TZID=Australia/Adelaide:'       . $eend_date . "T". $eend_time . "\r\n" .
  'LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en:'                . $location . "\r\n" .
  'SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en:'                 . $name . "\r\n" .
  'DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en:'             . $description . "\r\n" .
  'UID:'                                 . $id . "\r\n" .
  'DTSTAMP:'                             . date('Ymd') . "T". date('His') . "Z\r\n" .
  'END:VEVENT' . "\r\n";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check the specification but AFAIK the iCal file standard doesn't support that feature. You'd probably be better to use PHP to connect to the Google calendar API and send a meeting invite to the recipients that way, I'm pretty sure that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ADyson, I thought that was likely the case. I am over my head for the most part so thought it best to ask for help. On another but related note, I am under the impression that I cannot use the Google API (I was also told this by my hosting provider) as it requires a bit of setup on the server, outlined here [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php). I got it installed locally (WAMP), are you able to confirm this or have I been led astray by a lazy support assistant!? Cheers.

Comment: It's true that you probably can't use Composer on the hosting environment to automatically download the Google PHP code library, but there's nothing to stop you simply getting the files yourself and uploading them to the hosting account via FTP. That's really all the setup you would need. I use the Google calendar API in a few projects on shared hosting accounts and never had a problem

Comment: It was the authorisation step that I stumbled on. Perhaps it's worth starting another tread for that one.

Comment: Yes perhaps, we'd need specific details of the problem